# Sharing tools from a virtual machine to a host machine

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm

Host: Windows 7

Guest: [Vagrant box with virtual box] Ubuntu 14

Scenario: set up external tools (CodeSniffer, Code Standars Fixer, and so on) installed on the guest machine with a PhpStorm installed in the Windows host machine.

Normally you set up the bin path with the parameters if everything is installed in the host machine, but how it's done when you have your tools in the guest machine?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **External Tools** (which is for local execution) just use ... **[Remote SSH External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools)**.

**P.S.**
Make sure that "SSH Remote Run" plugin is enabled (should be by default).

Comment: That solve my question, but when everything is set up, how do you run the Code Sniffer Inspection tool? Seems you cant start the launcher from a remote ssh tool.. at least it only seems to allows you to select a local folder

Comment: Not sure that I follow you. Can you please specify what path you mean exactly with screenshots?

Comment: AFAIK: if all setup correctly (you have got SFTP deployment entry setup as Default for this project) then IDE should automatically convert local paths into remote. That's, of course, if you running your Code Sniffer as ordinary tool (at your request) and you check all results in terminal/console. For PHPCS remote integration (when IDE automatically launches CS for current file) you will have to wait till v9 -- it's already implemented. You may try v9 EAP build even now if so desired: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Answer (score 0):

I believe PhpStorm has [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/php-debugging-session.html) on how to achieve that.

Comment: I have the exact same setup you mentioned (vagrant-ubuntu guest and windows host), and was able to configure PhpStorm debugger to work by following the instruction on the link i provided. Please check again the "Zero-Configuration Debugging".